# C++ headers compilation error

Tags: c++

How can I run a C++ program containing header and namespaces(including filename.h) in one folder and the included header and namespaces in other folders?
The errors : "undefined reference to" and "no such directory".

Comment: Please be more specific. "some error" is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean including files from different folders, you have to add each of folders containing files to your include directories. And this differs, depending on your environment. E.g. in Visual Studio 2013 you would go:

```
Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories
```

Then you can open dialog box and add as many directories, as you need. This will add all files to your possible include files and you don't have to specify which folder specified in ,,Additional Include Directories" you're going to use.

Comment: As I said - it differs. I'm not familiar with this area of Linux. You have to check out documentation for proper command or text file to edit.

Answer (score 0):

For linux you can use

```
g++ -I/direct/path/to/the/file/containing/files <file>.cpp
```